# Find the start of a given week and year with Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a Delphi (10+) function that returns a TDate with a given year and a week number: 
`function StartDate(2021, 53): TDate` should return 2021-01-01.

While `WeekOfTheYear(EncodeDate(2021,1,1))` returns 53 (correct), I can't do the other way round with `StartOfAWeek(2021,53, 1)` nor `StartOfAWeek(2021,53, 5)` (5=it's a friday) - it's not recognized as a valid date (=exception). Any suggestions?

Edited:
I'm looking for a ISO 8601 compliant function (like the internal Delphi routines), with Monday=1 and special week consideration (like 2021-01-01), or to be more precise: the "vice versa" routine of `WeekOfTheYear`

Comment: Why should your function return `2021-01-01` if you pass there year 2021 and 53 weeks?

Comment: Which algorithm to use for week numbers? There are at least 2 that I know of (US and EU). Also: Which day is to be returned for the week? Sunday (as used in US) or Monday (as used in EU)? It's not a straight-forward question to answer...

Comment: @Victoria: because 2021-01-01 is the 53rd week

Comment: 53th week? Where are you from? :) If you meant that 53 as a number of weeks to increment to the given year, then it would be `2022-01-01`, not `2021-01-01`.

Comment: Yeah, in your example, week 53 of 2021 is actually at the start of 2022.

Comment: @Victoria: WeekOfTheYear(EncodeDate(2021,1,1)) returns 53 which is correct

Comment: @cydo Yes, but it's week 53 of 2020, at least the way I read the info on ISO 8601 at Wikipedia. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DH: so what week is 2021-1-1 then?

Comment: That's week 53 of 2020. A guiding principle is that weeks N+1 of year Y occurs after week N of year Y. How could 2021-1-1 be week 53 of 2021. Week 53 can't occur before weeks 1 to 52 in a year. From Wikipedia's ISO 8601 page: *If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, it is part of **week 53 of the previous year**. If it is on a Saturday, it is part of the last week of the previous year which is numbered 52 in a common year and 53 in a leap year. If it is on a Sunday, it is part of week 52 of the previous year.*

Comment: looks like I got it wrong. but that means I can't map year 2020 week 53 to 2021-01-01 because it could be 2020-12-28 as well

Comment: 2020-12-28 and 2021-01-01 are both week 53 of 2020. The first date is the First day (Monday) of week 53 of 2020. The second date is the 5th day (Friday) of week 53 of 2020. Week 1 of 2021 starts on 2021-01-04. The ISO standard says that the FIRST THURSDAY in a year lies in week 1 of that year, IIRC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you need is:

```
StartOfAWeek(Year, Week, 1)
```

You observe that `StartOfAWeek(2021, 53, 1)` raises an exception. That is correct because `2021` does not have 53 weeks. It only has 52. Week 52 ends on the last day of 2021.

You are getting confused by the result of

```
WeekOfTheYear(EncodeDate(2021,1,1))
```

This returns 53, but because the date is at the start of the year, this is week 53 of 2020.

Comment: I got that mixed up a little bit. But means I can't find the day at which the week 53 of 2020 starts - monday or friday.

Comment: In ISO8601 weeks start on Mondays. I'm confused by your comment therefore.

Comment: 2020-12-28 is Y2020W53 and 2021-01-01 is Y2020W53, so with only Y2020W53 I can't find the coresponding year. I'll give up then.

Comment: I'm sure the problem can be solved if I knew what it was. I just don't get the confusion yet.

Comment: I'm accessing a database where a calendar is stored per week. I have now found it has 2 columns Year;Week and there exists two rows, one with 2020;53 AND one with 2021;53 - I've tried to return a TDate with these informations and stumbled over the last one. Haven't thought about that 2021;53 isn't quite valid and there should be just ONE line in that db. ok. got it.

Comment: with 2020;53 the function should return 2020-28-12 and 2021;53 should return 2021-01-01, but I'm quite confident to solve it now by my own, was just confused about the 2021;53 entry. thank you

Comment: If that's the function you want then it's not adhering to any standard whatsoever and I fully expect that you are setting yourself up for problems down the line by devising a system where week 53 happens earlier than all the other weeks in the year.